# counting values and strings in different columns in a python dataframe separately?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

first post here for me (I've been googling all day and couldn't find anything), be gentle please.

so I am working with a dataframe with multiple columns, some floats, some booleans.

```
    col_1       col_2       col_3      col_4       col_5      col_6
0   38.109375   37.515625   True       False       (64, 69)   F
1   27.265625   28.484375   True       False       (74, 79)   M
2   26.843750   27.015625   False      True        (64, 69)   F
```

I want to re-order/make a new df which:

- is groupby col_6 AND col_5 (check)
- has the mean values of col_1 and col_2 (check)
- counts 'True' in col_3 and col_4 (doesn't work)

my approach so far:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['col_6', 'col_5']).agg({'col_5' : ['count'], 'col_1' : ['mean'], 'col_2' : ['mean']})
```

[Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLUga.png).

but I could not figure out how can I count the "trues" also related to col_5 and col_6? hope this makes sense and someone might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can count True items with lambda in agg function

```
new_df = (
    df
    .assign(
         col_3 = lambda x: x['col_3'].astype(int),
         col_4 = lambda x: x['col_4'].astype(int)
    )
    .groupby(['col_6', 'col_5'])
    .agg({'col_5' : ['count'], 
          'col_1' : ['mean'], 
          'col_2' : ['mean'],
          'col_3' : lambda x: len([1 for item in x if item ==True]),
          'col_4' : lambda x: len([1 for item in x if item ==True])}
     )
)
```

Comment: I tried your approach, worked very well. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Please check as correct answer so that other people have access to the correct answer ;)

Comment: a problem occurred with the code: if there was none or only one True in den respective columns, it wasn't counted as a number but true or false. Any explanation for that? do I like have to change the column type or something?

Comment: Yes that was because the column type was boolean, I updated the solution to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum booleans as you would ints:

```py
[ins] In [15]: df["y"]
Out[15]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: y, dtype: bool

[ins] In [16]: df["y"].sum()
Out[16]: 2
```

So you could use for instance `"col_3": ["sum"]` in your dictionary.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion, I've already used the suggestion by MhDG7